# Create a Polygon on Map using PyQt5. There are no errors but my polygon is not visible on map

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import os

class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('D:/SRIJA/Testing/QGis', True)
        QgsApplication.initQgis()
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        elf.lyr = QgsVectorLayer('D:/SRIJA/Testing/QGis/qgis_sample_data/shapefiles/airports.shp', 'airports', 'ogr')
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.lyr)
        self.canvas.setExtent(self.lyr.extent())
        self.canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(self.lyr)])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        actionZoomIn = QAction('Zoom in', self)
        actionZoomOut = QAction('Zoom out', self)
        actionPan = QAction('Pan', self)
        actionPoly = QAction('Polygon', self)
        actionPoly.setCheckable(True)
        self.connect(actionPoly, SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.poly)
        self.toolbar.addAction(actionPoly)
        self.toolPoly = PolyMapTool(self.canvas)
        self.toolPoly.setAction(actionPoly)
        self.poly()
        actionZoomIn.setCheckable(True)
        actionZoomOut.setCheckable(True)
        actionPan.setCheckable(True)
        actionZoomIn.triggered.connect(self.zoomIn)
        actionZoomOut.triggered.connect(self.zoomOut)
        actionPan.triggered.connect(self.pan)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Canvas actions')
        self.toolbar.addAction(actionZoomIn)
        self.toolbar.addAction(actionZoomOut)
        self.toolbar.addAction(actionPan)
        self.toolPan = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.toolPan.setAction(actionPan)
        self.toolZoomIn = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, False) # false = in
        self.toolZoomIn.setAction(actionZoomIn)
        self.toolZoomOut = QgsMapToolZoom(self.canvas, True) # true = out        
        self.toolZoomOut.setAction(actionZoomOut)
        self.pan()

def poly(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPoly)

def zoomIn(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomIn)

def zoomOut(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolZoomOut)

def pan(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.toolPan)
```

class MainApp(QApplication):

```
def __init__(self):
    QApplication.__init__(self,[],True)
    wdg = MyWnd()
    wdg.show()
    self.exec_()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = MainApp()
```

class PolyMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

```
def __init__(self, canvas):
    self.canvas = canvas
    QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
    self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QGis.Polygon)
    self.rubberband.setColor(Qt.red)
    self.rubberband.setWidth(1)
    self.point = None
    self.points = []

def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
    self.point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
    m = QgsVertexMarker(self.canvas)
    m.setCenter(self.point)
    m.setColor(QColor(0,255,0))
    m.setIconSize(5)
    m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_BOX)
    m.setPenWidth(3)
    self.points.append(self.point)
    self.isEmittingPoint = True
    self.showPoly()

def showPoly(self):
    self.rubberband.reset(QGis.Polygon)
    for point in self.points[:-1]:
        self.rubberband.addPoint(point, False)
        self.rubberband.addPoint(self.points[-1], True)
        self.rubberband.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a 'wall of code' question and personally, I'm not inclined to test it all, but I noticed a few problems with your map tool class.

I have modified your existing code a bit and it is working for me from the Python console in QGIS 3.4 to draw a rudimentary polygon rubber band with mouse clicks on the map canvas.

You should be able to simply copy this class into your standalone application script.

```
class PolyMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(Qt.red))
        self.rubberband.setFillColor(QColor(210, 153, 90, 125))
        self.rubberband.setWidth(1)
        self.points = []
        self.m = QgsVertexMarker(self.canvas)
        self.deactivated.connect(self.tool_deactivated)

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
        self.m.setCenter(point)
        self.m.setColor(QColor(0,255,0))
        self.m.setIconSize(5)
        self.m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_BOX)
        self.m.setPenWidth(3)
        self.points.append(point)
        self.isEmittingPoint = True
        self.showPoly()

    def showPoly(self):
        self.rubberband.reset(QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        for point in self.points[:-1]:
            self.rubberband.addPoint(point, False)
        self.rubberband.addPoint(self.points[-1], True)
        self.rubberband.show()

    def tool_deactivated(self):
        self.canvas.scene().removeItem(self.m)
        if self.rubberband is not None:
            self.rubberband.reset()

# Lines below are for running in Python Console
t = PolyMapTool(iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(t)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am unable to fetch the same result.Its a blank map on my screen

Comment: @Srija Harshika, Where did you get this code from? Which version of QGIS are you using? Looking into your `MyWnd` class it looks like you are mixing code from qgis versions 2 and 3 and Qt4 and Qt5. I'm very surprised you're not getting any errors.